# Use client usb signature in web application

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-core, oauth-2.0, x509certificate

I have an working C# winforms app that uses a usb signature to get oAuth2 bearer token,uses Client ID(edClientID.Text),Client Secret(edSecret.Text),Callback URL(uCalback),asks for usb signature password then returns access_token and refresh_token

```
string code;
readonly string URL_auth = "https://site1.com/authorize";
readonly string URL_getToken = "https://site1.com/token";
readonly char lfeed = (char)13;

Token token = null;

    try
    {

        string uCalback = HttpUtility.UrlEncode("https://www.site1.com");
        string url = string.Format("{0}?response_type=code&client_id={1}&redirect_uri={2}", URL_auth, edClientID.Text, uCalback);

        var handler = new WebRequestHandler
        {
            ClientCertificateOptions = ClientCertificateOption.Manual
        };


        var cert = GetUserCertificate();
        handler.ClientCertificates.Add(cert);


        handler.UseProxy = false;
        HttpClient client = new HttpClient(handler);
        string resultString;
        HttpResponseMessage result;
        
        try
        {
            result = client.GetAsync(url).GetAwaiter().GetResult();
        }
        ...

        if (result.RequestMessage.RequestUri.Query.Contains("code="))
        {
            code = result.RequestMessage.RequestUri.Query.Replace("?code=", "");

            var par = string.Format("grant_type=authorization_code&code={0}&client_id={1}&client_secret={2}&redirect_uri={3}",
                code, edClientID.Text, edSecret.Text, uCalback);
            try
            {
                result = client.PostAsync(URL_getToken, new StringContent(par)).GetAwaiter().GetResult();
                resultString = result.Content.ReadAsStringAsync().GetAwaiter().GetResult();
                if (resultString.Contains("access_token"))
                {

                    var js = new JavaScriptSerializer();
                    token = js.Deserialize<Token>(resultString);
                    ....

                }
            }
           .....
        }

    }

}




 public class Token
    {
        public string access_token { get; set; }
        public string refresh_token { get; set; }
    }

public static X509Certificate2 GetUserCertificate()
{
    X509Store store = new X509Store("MY", StoreLocation.CurrentUser);
    store.Open(OpenFlags.ReadOnly | OpenFlags.OpenExistingOnly);

    X509Certificate2Collection collection = store.Certificates;
    X509Certificate2Collection fcollection = collection.Find(X509FindType.FindByTimeValid, DateTime.Now, false);

    X509Certificate2Collection HardCollection = new X509Certificate2Collection();
    string sn = "";


    foreach (var x5 in fcollection)
    {
            if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(sn) || (x5.SerialNumber == sn))
                HardCollection.Add(x5);
    }
    if (HardCollection.Count > 1)
    {
        X509Certificate2Collection scollection = X509Certificate2UI.SelectFromCollection(HardCollection, "", "Select certificate", X509SelectionFlag.SingleSelection);
        store.Close();
        return scollection[0];
    }
    else
    {
        if (HardCollection.Count == 1)
        {
            store.Close();
            return HardCollection[0];
        }
        else
        {
            store.Close();
            return null;
        }
    }
}
```

I want to replace my winforms app with a web app(mywebapp.com),I've create a controller,but in this case,on the same computer If I go to mywebapp.com/cert/xxxxx/yyyy
it doesn't ask for usb signature,
If I put in browser the first GET request from the code  https://site1/authorize?response_type=code&client_id=xxxxx&redirect_uri=https%3a%2f%2fwww.site1.com
it asks for  usb signature

```
[ApiController]
[Route("[controller]")]
public class CertController : ControllerBase
{

    [HttpGet]
    [Route("/cert/{pClientID}/{pClientSecret}")]
    public IActionResult GetCert(string pClientID, string pClientSecret)
    {
        string code, uCalback, resultString;
        const char lfeed = (char)13;
        HttpResponseMessage result;
      

        try
        {

              uCalback = HttpUtility.UrlEncode("https://www.site1.com");
              const string URL_auth = "https://site1.com/authorize";
              const string URL_getToken = "https://site1.com/token";

            var cert = GetUserCertificate();

            var handler = new HttpClientHandler
            {
                ClientCertificateOptions = ClientCertificateOption.Manual,
                UseProxy = false
            };


            handler.ClientCertificates.Add(cert);

            HttpClient client = new HttpClient(handler);


            try
            {
                result = client.GetAsync(string.Format("{0}?response_type=code&client_id={1}&redirect_uri={2}",
                URL_auth, pClientID, uCalback)).GetAwaiter().GetResult();
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                throw new Exception(ex.Message);
            }

            if (result.RequestMessage.RequestUri.Query.Contains("code="))
            {
                code = result.RequestMessage.RequestUri.Query.Replace("?code=", "");

                var par = string.Format("grant_type=authorization_code&code={0}&client_id={1}&client_secret={2}&redirect_uri={3}",
                    code, pClientID, pClientSecret, uCalback);
                try
                {
                    result = client.PostAsync(URL_getToken, new StringContent(par)).GetAwaiter().GetResult();
                    resultString = result.Content.ReadAsStringAsync().GetAwaiter().GetResult();
                    if (resultString.Contains("access_token"))
                    {

                        Token o = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Token>(resultString);

                        return Ok($"access_token={o.access_token};refresh_token={o.refresh_token}");

                    }
                }
               .....
            }

        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
             ...
        }

    }
```

I think web app controller reads cerificates installed only on server machine not in client.
thanks for any help

Comment: What kind of scene do you expect?

Comment: when i go to mywebapp.com/cert/xxxxx/yyyy I want to see digital signture popup asking for password,just as winforms app does.I think web app reads ceritcates installed only on server machine not in client

Comment: Maybe this [link](https://www.red-gate.com/simple-talk/development/dotnet-development/beginning-with-digital-signatures-in-net-framework/) will help you.